# Trouble with SQL Command, with Declaration of table, inserting into it and outputting it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble making a SQL Command, where I want to declare a temporary table, insert into the stored table, and output the Id from the temporary table.

The reason I'm doing it like this, is to work around this error: "The target table '' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause." This is caused because I use the Sync Framework.

My insert statement is:

```
DECLARE InsertList TABLE ([ListId] INT) 
INSERT INTO [List] ([ListName]) VALUES(@ListName) 
OUTPUT [inserted].ListId INTO InsertList 
SELECT * FROM InsertList
```

But I get the error:

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near
>   'OUTPUT'."

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: declaration is missing @

Comment: ... and the VALUES() and OUTPUT clause must swap position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in SQL Server starts with an at (@) sign, even for table variables and the output clause is in the wrong place in the insert statement.

```
DECLARE @InsertList TABLE ([ListId] INT);

INSERT INTO [List] ([ListName]) 
OUTPUT [inserted].ListId INTO @InsertList 
VALUES(@ListName);

SELECT * FROM @InsertList;
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but you haven't declared @InsertList, will it work then?

Comment: @Thisen `@InsertList` is declared on the first line `DECLARE @InsertList TABLE ([ListId] INT);`.

Comment: But don't I need to give it a value like `@ListName`?

Comment: @Thisen You are inserting the value of `@ListName` to the table `List` and then you are capturing the output to the table variable `@InsertList`.

Answer (score 1):

In query You try to use Table type variable. Variables needs to be declared with @.

Correct code should be:

```
DECLARE @InsertList TABLE ([ListId] INT)
```